# Fast Floor and Ceiling alternatives for positive System.Double values

Tags: c#, .net, double, floor, ceil

```
double d = 0; // random decimal value with it's integral part within the range of Int32 and always positive.
int floored = (int) Math.Floor(d); // Less than or equal to.
int ceiled  = (int) Math.Ceiling(d); // Greater than or equal to.
int lessThan = ? // Less than.
int moreThan = ? // Greater than.
```

The Floor and ceiling functions include the largest/smallest integer that is less than/greater than **or equal to** `d` respectively. I want to find out the largest/smallest integer that is less than/greater than **but NOT equal to** `d` respectively.

OF course this can be achieved through a few `if's and but's` but I am looking for a method that either does not include branching or is at least a very fast since this operation will be performed billions of times in an algorithm.

Is binary manipulation possible? If not, what would be the best alternative?

The obvious solution would be something like:

```
int lessThan = (d - floored) > double.Epsilon ? floored : (floored-1);
int moreThan = (ceiled - d) > double.Epsilon ? ceiled : (ceiled+1);
```

**NOTE**: The objective is to find out whether `d` is closer to `lessThan` or `moreThan`.

Comment: Have you tried to implement it in using the few ifs and actually measured that it's too slow for you?

Comment: It's already implemented as above. I'm trying to speed up the algorithm by optimizing it in various ways.

Comment: Doesn't that mean you actually want to know whether `d % 1` is more than or less than a half or 0 (special case)?

Comment: @harold: That would do the trick with normal flooring and ceiling but not with `lessThan` and `moreThan` wouldn't it?

Comment: Well, with those the only difference occurs when `d % 1` is exactly zero (ie `d` is an integer), right?

Comment: @harold: I guess you could say that. The problem is that `d` is the base 2 log of a HUGE number. So huge that some precision is lost after a certain threshold. But then I guess there is no way to fix that is there? In which case, which do you think would be faster (the branching in my code or the modulus division in yours)?

Comment: Well, you can't get the precision back anyway.. and I don't know, taking the modulus of a float isn't the fastest thing in the world. I would just test it - also using my tricks to compute `lessThan` and `moreThan` (which are probably faster than your current way to compute them).

Comment: @harold: Sorry, the comments here took me away from your actual answer. I'll comment there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `d` is always positive, you can use that casting to an integer truncates (ie it's the floor for positive input and the ceiling for negative input).

`floor(d + 1)` is the same as `ceil(d) + 1 if integer, ceil(d) otherwise` and `ceil(d - 1)` is the same as `floor(d) - 1 if integer, floor(d) otherwise`

```
int moreThan = (int)(d + 1); // floor(d + 1)
int lessThan = int.MaxValue + (int)((d - int.MaxValue) - 1) // ceil(d - 1)
```

The `lessThan` is somewhat convoluted, I wouldn't be surprised if someone else has a better idea.

But since you want this:

> The objective is to find out whether d is closer to lessThan or moreThan

It should be even simpler:

```
double x = d % 1;
if (x == 0 || x == 0.5)
    // d is equally far from either one, either by a difference of 1 or of 0.5
else if (x < 0.5)
    // d is closer to lessThan
else
    // d is closer to moreThan
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand moreThan. Could you please explain why you use int.MaxValue for lessThan?

Comment: @RaheelKhan the idea there is to "shift" (as opposed to "mirroring", which is what negation would do) `d` into the negatives so that casting to int rounds the other way. It doesn't have to be `int.MaxValue`, just the maximum value that `d` can take.

Comment: Perfect. I just did some comparison and overhead of addition / subtraction is far less than branching on the target. Will just make sure if there are any corner cases to be considered for lessThan.

Comment: Btw your idea of Ceil() => return (int)(d + 1); Ceil(d = 16) returns 17. your should change it to something like (d+0.999999999999998d), this way integer double numbers (1, 2, 3, 4 ... ) shall not be rounded up and still faster from original Math.Ceiling(). ps: d % 1 seams to be very costly operation and should be optimized differently.

Comment: @SoLaR but I did not write that ceil is equal to `(int)(d + 1)` (which you correctly note that it isn't), the goal is specifically to find a value *greater than* `d` which is kind of like a ceil but except that it's one higher than ceil for an integer input

Answer (score 0):

I can missunderstand question, but to find nearest integer value of d:

```
int floored = (int)d;
int ceiled = (int)(d + 1);
int mathRounded = (int)(d + 0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what results you want to achieve at the end.

If you want the **ceil**, **floor** and what is the **closest**:

```
int lessThan = (int) Math.Floor(d); // Less than or equal to.
int moreThan = (int) Math.Ceiling(d); // Greater than or equal to.

// 1 comparison instead of 2 that is made on your question.
if (lessThan == moreThan)
{
    lessThan--;
    moreThan++;
 }

 bool isCloserToFloor = (d - .5) < lessThan;
 bool isCloserToCeil = !isCloserToFloor;
```

Comment: Your if branch will never be hit.

Comment: Why not? Math.Floor and Math.Ceiling will return the same integer if the floor and ceiling are equal to `d`. Test it and tell me.

Comment: Ummm... Not sure I understand, Floor and Ceiling will only be the same if `d` were itself an integer (which will not be the case here).

Comment: Well, the only way the Floor and Ceil return a value that is _equal_ to `d` is if `d` itself is an integer (on a decimal struct). If you're sure that `d` will never be an integral value, then you don't need to make any check, just use `Math.Floor` and `Ceiling` that you will always get the correct values for lessThan and moreThan.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't perf tested this but you could test to see if your double is an integer already and then perform the appropriate operation:

```
double d = 0;
int lessThan;
int moreThan;

if (d % 1 == 0)
{
    lessThan = d - 1;
    moreThan = d + 1;
}
else
{
    lessThan = (int) Math.Floor(d);
    moreThan  = (int) Math.Ceiling(d);
}
```

Comment: If `(d - ((int) d)` is less than `double.Epsilon`, then `d % 1 == 0` would also be true right?

Comment: I believe so for positive values of d.

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat a bit: use Convert.ToInt32(bool):

```
double d = 0; // random decimal value with it's integral part within the range of Int32 and always positive.
int floored = (int) Math.Floor(d); // Less than or equal to.
int ceiled  = (int) Math.Ceiling(d); // Greater than or equal to.
int lessThan = floored - Convert.ToInt32(Math.Abs(d-floored) < epsilon);
int moreThan = ceiled + Convert.ToInt32(Math.Abs(d-ceiled) < epsilon);
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain the last two lines please.

Comment: @Raheel Khan: Convert.ToInt32(true) == 1; Convert.ToInt32(false) == 0; We just want to substract 1 when Math.Abs(d-floored) < epsilon and add 1 when Math.Abs(d-ceiled) < epsilon and do nothing in other case. Convert.ToInt32(bool) is exactly what we need

Comment: Hmmm... I like the syntax but will have to test this. Convert.ToInt32 is a method call and the overhead may outweigh even branching.

Comment: @Raheel Khan: Could you please tell the results of the test here, I am really interested about the speed of this code in the release mode

Comment: Keeping harold's reply above as the benchmark (5.64 seconds) for 1 billion iterations of my function, replacing with your code takes about 6.26 seconds. That is (four add/subtract, 2 casts) versus (two add/subtract, two functions, one comparison) in your case. The difference adds up since I using this for an algorithm that runs for hours on end.